# how to recursively find files in shell

Tags: shell

I am trying the below :

```
find /dir1/dir2/dir3 -name '*.txt' -type f
```

What I want to do is I want to search for files recursively in the dir3 folder. That means under dir3 there are dir4 and dir5 folders and I want that the files matching with *txt extension should be returned from dir4 and dir5 directories. Also, how can I get the files which are only created on today's date?

Comment: `I am trying the below :` So did it work?

Comment: I am getting files from dir3 but not from further dir4 and dir5 . And yes there are .txt files present there.

Comment: `but not from further dir4 and dir5` That would be odd - it should work. [Cannot reproduce - works on repl.it](https://replit.com/@kamilcukrowski/ZigzagSneakyBundledsoftware#main.sh). `And yes there are .txt files present there` I trust `find` - it does not report the files, they are not there.

Comment: No idea but its relly not working, its very strange, is there an other alternative?

Comment: There is `ls -R`, `shopt -s extglob nullglob` with `printf "%s\n" *.txt **/*.txt`, user programs and loops. But anyway, `find` is the most basic standard guaranteed tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use bash, I came up with this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# This depends on your systems locale I think.
# for me, `date` returns `So 25. Jul 12:32:27 CEST 2021`.
# Therefore I want the $2 for DAY and $3 for MONTH, yours might be different.
DAY="$(date | awk '{print $2}')" 
MONTH="$(date | awk '{print $3}')"
FINDIN="/dir1/dir2/dir3"

# This prints only `.txt` files which were created today along with all their details.
# If you only want the path, you could pipe it into
# `awk '{print $11}'`
find "$FINDIN" -type f -ls | grep -E "*.txt$" | grep "$MONTH $DAY"
```

Using bashisms you could technically make this a (lengthy) one-liner but if you put it in a script, you can substitute your path (`$FINDIN`) for a dynamic value passed as an argument (`$1`, `$2`, …) or the caller directory (implied/parsed from `$0`).